# correct way to get folder name from input

Tags: bash, stdin

I wrote one script and I have problem to get name of folder from stdin
here is my problem;

`myfunc`:

```
 #!/bin/bash

audio=$1

mkdir -p ${audio}_rnn

...
rest of code
...
```

I call my function:

```
$./myfunc testdir
```

in this way I have my expected output, that means I have another dir with name testdir_rnn in the current directory.

But when I call my function like this:

```
$./myfunc testdir/
```

I have problem; it create _rnn folder inside testdir folder becaues:
echo ${audio}_rnn in this case is testdir/_rnn

What is the correct way to get folder name from input?

Comment: basename $1 assuming that you provide name consisting of just dir name (and not upper levels) would be a solution here

Comment: The problem is the trailing slash "/"). To remove it, use ${audio%/} (removed the trailing slash if present, otherwise leave the value alone), so you have mkdir -p ${audio%/}_rnn

Answer (score 6):

You just need to trim the '/'. Please use `${1%/}` in your code as below:

```
audio=${1%/}

mkdir -p ${audio}_rnn

...
rest of code
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you could remove the last "/" with sed using regular expressions:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo 'Dir/test/' | sed 's/\/$//'
```

Output: Dir/test

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that directory will be passed without the upper levels.
You can use somthing like `cut`

`#!/bin/bash`

`my_dir=$(echo $1 | cut -d "/" -f1)`

`mkdir -p "${my_dir}_rnn"`

....
rest of the code
....

Now run the script with
`./my_script.sh test_dir` or `./my_script.sh test_dir/` (both will work).

Comment: You assume there is only one level of directory, so this will fail if you have testdir1/subdir2/ as the parameter. Use the ${audio%/} fix that I suggested first.

Answer (score -1):

Add a period (.) before the variable, can fix this issue as per your need.

```
  #!/bin/bash 
audio=$1 
mkdir -p .${audio}_rnn
```

But for this to create a dir _rnn, you must already have testdir/ already in place.

Comment: I do not see how that addresses the question.